# How to set Password property of oledb connection in SSIS package

Tags: oledbconnection, ssis-2008

I am new to SSIS, here is the issue I am facing.
1) Created an OLEDB connection to connect to database. Storing the Connection String in SSIS variable and have added expression to Connection Manager to pick the connection string according to environment.
2) Have used Windows Authentication to connect to database, so that no need to provide user ID and Password. In development environment it worked perfectly fine. But when moved to testing environment, its failing with Error **"SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "REGEDB" failed with error code 0xC0202009"** 
3) Using SQL Server Configuration to deploy the package. But getting error **Failed to load at least one of the configuration entries for the package. Check configuration entries for "CBPSSIS" and previous warnings to see descriptions of which configuration failed.**
Below is the Connection String
Data Source=abcd\ISQLQ02;Initial Catalog=DRIP;Provider=SQLNCLI10;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False; 
COuld you please let me know how to set Password property? I tired in Script file but its not working. Thank you

ConnectionManager OldedbConn;
 OldedbConn = Dts.Connections["QAREGE"];          Dts.Connections["QAREGE"].Properties["ServerName"].SetValue(OldedbConn, Dts.Variables["User::dbServerName"].Value);            Dts.Connections["QAREGE"].Properties["InitialCatalog"].SetValue(OldedbConn, Dts.Variables["User::dbCatalog"].Value);            Dts.Connections["QAREGE"].Properties["UserName"].SetValue(OldedbConn, Dts.Variables["User::dbUserID"].Value);            Dts.Connections["QAREGE"].Properties["Password"].SetValue(OldedbConn, Dts.Variables["User::dbPwd"].Value);

Comment: Can anyone please help me? I changed Delay Validation to True for all db connection related tasks. Getting below error "Failed to acquire connection "REGEDB". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection." SSIS package is executed through SQL job and by System Admin which will have full right on database. Not understanding why it is still faling. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `ssis-2008` you can create a ssis configFile with `.dtsConfig` format with `xml configuration file type`. Include all your `Database connection string` in the config file. So when you moved your ssis package to another server you just need to edit the config file and set your connection based on your target server.